# Stubbing for final Class method from another Public Class in Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I Need to **Stub** the **Final Class** **method** in other **public class** method.
My scenario, I have a Class name **ElasticIntegration** which is Public class. There is a method called **licenseCheckOut**

```
public Response licenseCheckOut(String jsonObj) {
    LogResource logData = new LogResource();
    try {
        LicenseServiceImpl licenseCheck = new LicenseServiceImpl();
        JSONObject queryObj = new JSONObject(jsonObj);
        int licenseId = -1;         
        Properties configProperties = Utilities.getConfigProperties();      
        Utilities.verifykeycloakToken(queryObj, configProperties);
        String userName = userAuth.getUserInfo(queryObj,configProperties);
        if(userName !=null){
            licenseId = licenseCheck.checkoutLicense(userName);
        }
        String result = "{\"licenseid\": "+ licenseId +"}";
        return Response.ok(result).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogDetail details = Utilities.constructDetails("licenseCheckOut", ex);
        logData.writeLogMessage(null, details);
        return Response.serverError().entity(details).build();
    }
}
```

Within **licenseCheckOut** method there is **verifykeycloakToken** is the method which we need to stub. **Utilities** **class** is the **final** class.

[image: **verifykeycloakToken Function in Utilities class**]

If you check with the Above Image reference exactly **connection.connect()** we are getting the error. So I stubbed class with **when(*).thenReturn(*)**

```
    Utilities util = new Utilities();
    Utilities mock = mock(Utilities.class);
    JSONObject queryObj = new JSONObject(jsonObj);
    Properties mapProperties = null ;
    when(mock.verifykeycloakToken(queryObj, mapProperties)).thenReturn(true);
```

Error I am getting here is

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
>   Cannot mock/spy class com.project.Utilities
>   Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
>    - final class
>       at ElasticIntegrationTest.licenseCheckOut_verifykeycloakToken_ShouldReturnSuccessBuild(ElasticIntegrationTest.java:51)

Answer (score 1):

Your `verifykeycloakToken` method in `Utilities`class is a `static` method.

*To mock this* you can explore following options:

- Mock everything inside `verifykeycloakToken` function. That seems
  little difficult to do in your case as you are creating `new URL()`
  object inside it, which `mockito` can't handle.
- Use [powermockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Getting-Started) because mocktio alone can't handle the `static` mocking.

**PS:** Using `powermock` is *generally frowned upon* especially if you are following ***TDD***. But it really comes into rescue while working with *legacy code*.